# scidb installation on single debian server

Tags: scidb

I would like to try scidb as a replacement for hdf5. I would like to test it on my Debian laptop (no clusters) to give it a try.

Is this possible? Might be that Debian (as opposed to Ubuntu) is not supported?

I had no luck with the installation instructions. The deployment script tells that my OS is not supported. The scidb userguide says about some pre-built packages (for Ubuntu, at least). But there is no hint on how to obtain them.

Answer (score 1):

SciDB is limited to RedHat / CentOS, and to Ubuntu as of the 14.9 release. Folk who want to run it on other distros generally compile from code.

Information about how to obtain the sources (as well as current documentation and community discussion) can be found on the forums here ... http://www.scidb.org/forum/. You'll need to register as a forum user.

Specifically, have a look at http://www.scidb.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=364. There's a list of releases and links to code bundles there.

Answer (score 1):

I installed SciDB several times using several ways (building from sources and installing from packages, installing the cluster version and the dev version).

### Installation from packages

First, if you choose to install from packages (the easiest and fastest way), SciDB is very very sensitive about your Linux version. For example, for the last version of SciDB (14.8), if you choose to install on a Ubuntu, it has to be a Ubuntu 12.04 (and not a 14.04, a common mistake) 64 bits (meaning you have to install the AMD64 version even if you have an Intel processor). It won't work if you have a different version.

If you have an Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64, Paradigm4 provides a deployment script and a documentation with very simple steps:

- https://github.com/Paradigm4/deployment

### Installation from sources

It's not so difficult but it can be painful and time consuming. I did it because we had to compile a custom plugin for SciDB. You have two types of installation: dev install (in SciDB user directory) and cluster install (in /opt/ directory).

You have to be registered on their forum to have the link to the source code. They provide a specific documentation to build from source.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago I have dealt with porting SciDB 14.12 to an unsupported Linux - Fedora 19. If your OS is not supported, it will neither be supported if you try to install from the sources. You have to start from the sources, but then you have to adapt the deployment and installation scripts. The sources can be downloaded from [SciDB forum](http://paradigm4.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1596).

Namely, add a new platform to `deployment/common/os_detect.sh`. Then, there are multiple platform specific deployment scripts, such as `deployment/common/prepare_toolchain.sh`, `deployment/common/prepare_coordinator.sh` and `deployment/common/prepare_chroot.sh`. You need to make sure those prepare the environment as they would on the supported OS'. I used Red Hat 6 and CentOS 6 as a reference, as those are both more similar to Fedora. Since your OS is Debian, you can first try falling back to Ubuntu deployment (in `os_detect.sh`).

Another problem you may encounter are the 3rd party tools, specially Boost. In my case, I had to build it manually from sources.

Sometimes when porting and debugging it is not convenient to run the scripts with `deploy.sh`, but it's better to run the deployment scripts directly on the target machine (e.g. coordinator).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to install and to start with SciDB is to download a standard image. With this image you only have to import the virtual machine with a software to virtualize. Moreover there are some characteristics of this virtual machine that are great to develop your first applications.

The main advantage, is that you have an API to SciDB queries and another to R. Then you can explore all options and to test SciDB.

This is the version that I downloaded few months ago: http://www.paradigm4.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1329&sid=606f614e401900cfa750375ba56de656

Nevertheless, there is a problem, the community is too poor. There are little people developing with SciDB.